# I have an layout in which there there is hierarchy of view, linearlayout + recyclerview+textview ,Now these all view are under the scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/twentysp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.fizzy.reached.Activities.AddEventActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_add_event">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tendp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_grey"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_title"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:hint="Event title"
        android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:singleLine="true" />
    <!--<fragment-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"-->
    <!--/>-->

    <!--<fragment-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/event_title"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"-->
    <!--/>-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/event_location"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_title"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_location"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:editable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:hint="Event Location"
        android:padding="@dimen/fifteen" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_location"></fragment>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/event_notes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/map"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_title"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:hint="Event Notes"
        android:padding="@dimen/fifteen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_event_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_notes"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/tendp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Date &amp; Time"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fifteen" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/event_date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_event_date"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_date"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/event_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_date"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_time"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/fifteen"
        android:hint="Time"
        android:padding="@dimen/fifteen" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_participants"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/event_time"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/tendp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Participants"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/fifteen" />
    <!--<LinearLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/linear_add_participant"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->

    <!--<ImageView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/img_add_participant"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"-->
    <!--android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"-->
    <!--android:src="@drawable/ic_add_participant" />-->
    <!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/txt_add_participant"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_add_participant"-->
    <!--android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"-->
    <!--android:text="Add Participant"-->
    <!--android:textColor="@color/blue"-->
    <!--android:textSize="@dimen/twentysp" />-->
    <!--</LinearLayout>-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
        android:text="Current user"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/tendp"
        android:text="Current user"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <!--android:paddingBottom="@dimen/thirtytwo"-->
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_add_participant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_add_participant"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_participant" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_add_participant"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img_add_participant"
            android:padding="@dimen/fifteen"
            android:text="Add Participant"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/twentysp" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <!--<View-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/view"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="0.7dp"-->
    <!--android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />-->
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

While adding the view, i am not able to see the last textview placed below the recyclerview.

And I also try to put that textview in footer of recyclerview, from that the listview is scrollable to itself and it shows that footer textview but not while scrolling the recyclerview.

[image: The list of participant can be increased at run time]

The list is dynamic so i have taken the recyclerview.

Let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: question seems unclear. please try explaining it better and adding screenshot and xml code

Comment: you have not shown the full heirarchy in xml. scrollview etc are missing their width/height lines

Comment: @Shubhank I have pasted the full code

Comment: you are having a recycle view inside scrollview. this will definitely create issues. have you tried giving wrap height to the recycle view ?

Comment: yes i have given wrapcontent as well. but no use.

Comment: when i click on add participant and add the participant ,the label add participant hides.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113934/discussion-between-shubhank-and-ritu-nagpal).